# (Host Django Pythonanywhere) Manage.py collectstatic returns FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Hi I deployed a python Django app on www.pythonanywhere.com, the app works fine, but when I try to run manage.py collectstatic I get this error
here is my code at settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/djangopaste/DjangoPaste/djangohost/static'
```

Project Directory to settings.py
`/home/djangopaste/DjangoPaste/djangohost/`
Project Directory to manage.py
`/home/djangopaste/DjangoPaste/djangohost`

Traceback error

````
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 131, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/home/djangopaste/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 315, in listdir
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/djangopaste/DjangoPaste/djangohost/static'```
````

Comment: Do you actually have a directory at `/home/djangopaste/DjangoPaste/djangohost/static`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djangohost', 'static')
```

Comment: It's not working @Katoozi , I tried that it gives same error,